# String.replace() method not working

Tags: java, string, replace

I am working on a big project at my firm where I have encountered a strange error while working with replace method for String.

Here is the Scenario:

I am taking values from properties file using a singleton class that retrieves these properties. I have a String of DATA which includes two replacement keys which are supposed to be replaced with values generated programatically.

For example:

```
String strDetails = PropertyLoader.get("details");
String strDataKey1= PropertyLoader.get("datakey1");
String strDataKey2 = PropertyLoader.get("datakey2");

strDetails = strDetails.replace(strDataKey1, "Programmatically Generated Value 1");

strDetails = strDetails.replace(strDataKey2, "Programmatically Generated Value 2");
```

in the above code replacement of `strDataKey1` is working but `strDataKey2` isn't.

I created simple Java program to test this and it worked in the same way I tried debugging the code in the above two lines all values are coming as expected, but the result of replacement fails for `strDataKey2`.

Note - Both `strKey1` and `strKey2` have special character `'$'`.
Please advise if anyone knows how to fix it. I am using Eclipse latest version for JavaEE I cannot use other IDEs at my firm.

Comment: Try to print to console `strDataKey1` and `strDataKey2` and see their values.

Comment: close your class tab and reopen it.

Comment: This is independent of the ide, eclipse is not the problem. Also the dollar sign should not be a problem - replace does not use regular expressions (but replaceAll does). As the other comment says, try to print out the values at each step

Comment: This is entirely a Java problem, it has nothing to do with the IDE (Eclipse) that you are using. What are the actual values of `strDetails`, `strDataKey1` and `strDataKey2`?

Comment: Try printing all these values and maybe you'll get some hints.

Comment: It would be better if you show us values of `PropertyLoader.get("details")`,
`PropertyLoader.get("datakey1")` and 
`PropertyLoader.get("datakey2")`

Comment: Your choice of IDE is irrelevant

Comment: it looks like it has something to do with your input rather than with java or ide which you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems strDetails does'nt have strDataKey2 when you are doing 2nd replace.
Try resetting like below and see if it works

```
String strDetails = PropertyLoader.get("details");
String strDataKey1= PropertyLoader.get("datakey1");
String strDataKey2 = PropertyLoader.get("datakey2");
String strDetailsOrg = strDetails;

strDetails = strDetails.replace(strDataKey1, "Programmatically Generated Value 1");

strDetailsOrg = strDetailsOrg.replace(strDataKey2, "Programmatically Generated Value 2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `strDataKey1` and `strDataKey2` have complementary values.

Example:

```
strDataKey1 = "foo";
strDataKey2 = "foobar"; 
strDetails = "foobar foo bar 123 foobar foo";

strDetails = strDetails.replace(strDataKey1, "Value1"); //4 matches
//strDetails is "Value1bar Value1 bar 123 Value1bar Value1"

strDetails = strDetails.replace(strDataKey2, "Value2"); //0 matches
//strDetails is "Value1bar Value1 bar 123 Value1bar Value1"
```

When you replace `strDataKey1` you *"consume"* the anchor and then, replacing `strDataKey2`, you have no modification.

Check the values in `strDataKey1` and `strDataKey2` and do some consideration about them, like wrapping them with a sentinel value, an escape character or a delimiter (if it can solve the problem).